# How to explicitly bind variables in an induction proof?

Tags: isabelle

I have a datatype and an inductive predicate over it (which is actually a small-step semantics of some transition system):

```
datatype dtype = E | A | B dtype

inductive dsem :: "dtype ⇒ dtype ⇒ bool" where  
  "dsem A E"
| "dsem (B E) E"
| "dsem d d' ⟹ dsem (B d) (B d')"
```

and also a function which is computed by case distinction:

```
fun f :: "dtype ⇒ nat" where
  "f E = 0"  
| "f A = 1"
| "f (B _) = 2"
```

I'm trying to prove some property about the inductive predicate, and assumptions also involve computing the value of `f` which doesn't participate in induction.

```
lemma
  assumes d: "dsem s s'"
    and h: "h s v"
    and v: "v = f s"
  shows "P v"
using d h
proof (induct rule: dsem.induct)
```

For the 3rd semantics rule Isabelle computes the subgoal

```
⋀d d'. dsem d d' ⟹ (h d v ⟹ P v) ⟹ h (B d) v ⟹ P v
```

where the value of `s` is lost so it is impossible to compute the value `v`.
I can neither include `v` into the induction assumptions because then Isabelle generates the subgoal

```
⋀d d'. dsem d d' ⟹ (h d v ⟹ v = f d ⟹ P v) ⟹ h (B d) v ⟹ v = f (B d) ⟹ P v
```

where the induction hypothesis says `v = f d` which is incorrect since `v = f (B d)` in this case. Nor can I put `v` into `arbitrary: ...` because the value of `v` must be fixed throughout the proof.

It would be nice to have an explicit binding `s = B d` in the generated subgoal; unfortunately, the rule `dsem.induct` doesn't provide it.

Does anybody know a workaround for computing the value `v` in this case?

Comment: Does it help to rephrase your lemma as `lemma "dsem s s' ⟹ (⋀v. ⟦ h s v ; v = f s ⟧ ⟹ P v)"`?

Comment: Since the fact `v` (i.e., `v = f s`) contains the variable `s` and you are doing induction on `dsem s s'` (which also contains `s`) there is no way around also including `v` into the induction assumptions. If the statement is not provable after doing so, you will have to reformulate it appropriately (whatever that means).

Comment: @JohnWickerson No, it is the same problem.

Comment: You might try the proof with assumption `v` unfolded, i.e. `lemma "dsem s s' ⟹ h s (f s) ⟹ P (f s)"`. This version is logically equivalent to the one stated in the question (and to the one suggested by John Wickerson above).

Answer (score 1):

It seems strange to me that `v` should be at the same time fixed and computed from `s` and that is what [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476803/chris) is saying in the comments.

If the solution [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2162023/brian-huffman) gives in the comments is what you want, it could duplicate the expression `f s` which could be big (and use `s` several times) and perhaps the point of the assumption `v = f s` was to avoid this.

A first workaround (that was possibly what [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2162023/brian-huffman) implicitly proposed) is to make Isabelle do the `unfolding`:

```
lemma
  assumes d: "dsem s s'"
    and h: "h s v"
    and v: "v = big_f s s"
  shows "P v"
using d h
unfolding v -- {* <<<< *}
proof (induct rule: dsem.induct)
```

A second workaround could be to abbreviate `big_f` instead of `big_f s s`:

```
lemma
  assumes d: "dsem s s'"
    and h: "h s (f s)"
    and v: "f = (λs. big_f s s)" -- {* <<<< *}
  shows "P (f s)"
using d h
proof (induct rule: dsem.induct)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately, all these propositions lead to the described issue. The lemma in the form I wanted it seems to be unprovable, so I had to reformulate it.